# "Куда мы?" или "куда мы пойдем?"

Tags: грамматика

"Куда мы?" and "куда мы пойдем?" are the same?
and meaning of both are these:

- Where will we go?
- Where are we going?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they mean those two things.

But if you choose to use `Куда мы?`, you should remember it's more colloquial:

> Mother: Куда вы?
>
> Children: В парк.

=

> Mother: Куда вы *идёте*? (at the moment of speaking or in the nearest future)
>
> Children: В парк.

`Куда вы пойдёте?` can only mean future. Use `идёте` or just `куда вы?` if you need to refer to the moment of speaking.

Comment: Спасибо вам большое

Comment: @WorldLover не за что ;-)

Comment: I would also add that I've never heard "Куда **мы**?" used by any native speaker (which doesn't mean you can't say that, but to me that would sound really off) in a conversation. So I'd say it's best to avoid using this short form.

Comment: @ArthurKazykhanov I can't agree with that. I have certainly heard people say "куда мы?" and I'm sure I've said it myself (I am a native speaker). But sure enough, there are times when "куда мы?" is appropriate and there are times when it's not.

Answer (score 3):

IMO, those versions are used in *different* situations.

"**Куда мы**?" A typical context: a small group of people walks down the street but unexpectedly for the speaker everyone else changes their direction and that's when the question is asked. Its sense: '*where are we heading to **now**?*' The question is incomplete since the verb **идём** (going/heading to) is omitted.

"**Куда мы пойдем?** (*Where **shall** we go?*) That's simply about plans for the nearest **future**.

Comment: It is nuanced: "Куда мы пойдём" vs "Куда мы идём" (+1 anyways)